# Is there are another way to access victim website admin panel without sql injection or redirect bypass?

Tags: cpanel

I learned to access some website admin panels with SQL injection and redirect bypass method. (Blocking 302 redirect via browser extension)

But I saw someone accessing popular website admin panels using different ways. (They called it "Admin Pwnd")

If you know any other methods to do it, please share it with us.

Comment: Welcome. Questions asking for open-ended lists of methods is not the question format that StackExchange allows.